# I have to open Visual Studio Code as administrator or I won't be able to open a terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I have the latest version of Visual Studio Code installed on a [Windows 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10) machine. If I run Visual Studio Code regularly, so not as an administrator, then if I try to open a terminal I get a 740 error. If I start Visual Studio Code with administrator privileges everything works fine.

What could be causing this? I would prefer if I didn't have to run Visual Studio Code with administrator privileges.

P.S.

- I'm using Visual Studio Code's integrated Terminal.
- If I switch to Command Prompt as external Terminal, the problem is gone. But I would prefer to continue to use the integrated Terminal.
- There are some other Slack topics that point to ensure not running Visual Studio Code in compatibility mode, which is indeed disabled on my end.

Comment: Are you running Windows or Linux? I am guessing windows since your using the term Admin, but it would help to clarify. So linux users can by pass this question, and windows experts can try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the cause. Git Bash was configured as the Integrated Terminal of VSC. Its run file C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe was configured in Windows to "Run as Administrator". As a result, I also had to start VSC "as administrator" to open a Terminal. After unchecking the box "Run as Administrator" for Git Bash, I no longer need to run VSC as administrator to be able to open the Terminal.